Why do unit quaternions span $S^3$ space, while rigid body configuration represented by them span $S^2 \times S^1$?
I'm reading "Modern Robotics" by Lynch and Park and came to realize that the rigid body configuration space is not $\mathbb{R}^3 \times S^3$, but rather $\mathbb{R}^3 \times S^2 \times S^1$ (you can choose the first point of the rigid body arbitrarily in space, then choose the second point on the surface of a sphere, and finally choose the third point on a circle).
This was confusing to me because I'm used to representing rigid body attitude with a unit quaternion, which I understand spans $S^3$ space. I'm aware that unit quaternions cover all possible orientations twice, but I still don't see how these two spaces are topologically similar. Am I missing something?

It is also possible to represent the configuration space as $\mathbb R^3\times SO(3)$ which is pretty close to $\mathbb R^3\times S^3\cong\mathbb R^3\times SU(2),.$ Now you need to study the relationship of $SU(2)$ and $SO(3),.$ For someone familiar with rotations and unit quaternions  I suppose it is known that $SU(2)$ is the double cover of $SO(3),.$


choose the second point on the surface of a sphere, and finally choose the third point on a circle

These two steps do not lead to $S^2\times S^1$, actually, they lead to ${\rm SO}(3)$.
Consider the Mobius strip $M$. Draw a circle around it, then fill $M$ with line segments drawn through each point of the circle. Picking a point in $M$ involves first picking a point on the circle, then picking a point on the line segment through it. But that doesn't mean $M\simeq S^1\times[0,1]$, because the line segments are "twisted" along $S^1$ whereas in the cylinder $S^1\times[0,1]$ they are not.
Here's another example. Interpret $S^1\subset\Bbb C$ as the unit circle in the complex plane. You can pick a value in $S^1$ by first picking a value $z\in S^1$ and then picking one of the two values $\pm\sqrt{z}$. But this doesn't mean we can say that $S^1\simeq S^1\times S^0$. If you think of $S^1\times S^0$ as a pair of rubber bands, you can track along both $S^1$s with your fingers and your fingers can end up back where they started, but if you think of $S^1$ as a "doubled-up" rubber band, you can track two fingers along it but the fingers end up swapped once you go around.
The Mobius band is an example of a nontrivial fiber bundle $[0,1]\to M\to S^1$. When the fibers are discrete (like the two fingers $\simeq S^0$ for the rubber bands), this is a covering space. In particular, the "doubled-up" rubber band is a nontrivial connected double covering, or fiber bundle $S^0\to S^1\to S^1$.
Similarly, in your case, since the circle you're choosing the third point from is varying with respect to the second point, it turns out these "circles" within the configuration space are irrevocably twisted within it, just like the line segments in a Mobius band. The configuration space (around the first chosen point of the rigid body) is a nontrivial fiber bundle $S^1\to{\rm SO}(3)\to S^2$ which is distinct from $S^1\times S^2$.
Moreover, there is a double cover $S^3\to{\rm SO}(3)\simeq\mathbb{RP}^2$ based on how quaternions model 3D rotations in a $2$-to-$1$ fashion (each rotation corresponds to an antipodal pair $\pm p$ of unit quaternions). Therefore, the configuration space (around the first point) is the quotient space $S^3/S^0\simeq{\rm SO}(3)$, technically. For practical purposes one may just use the space $S^3$ instead.
